# Compare two times and launch in app-notification if so

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I'm currently trying to use a pod called BRYXBanner to display in-app notifications, and in my alarm app I would like it so that when the alarm time is reached(compared to the current time), a notification should pop up. However, for some reason I can't do this correctly. I would appreciate it if someone could guide me.

**Below is some of my notification code:**

*This is the tableView cellForRowAt indexpath method.*

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "alarmCell", for: indexPath) as! DisplayAlarmCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    let alarm = alarms[row] // my alarm object at the row

    var ref: DatabaseReference
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    let date = Date() // current date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat  = "EEEE"//"EE" to get short style
    let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    cell.alarmTitle.text = alarm.alarmLabel // alarm object property for label
    cell.clockTitle.text = alarm.time // alarm object property for time

for weekdays in weekdaysChecked { //goes through an array to check if today is equal to the day in the array.

            if(dayInWeek == weekdays){

                if(state == .active || state == .inactive) { // checks if app is in foreground

                    let time = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: dateA!)//dateA is a TimePickerView's date
                    let date = Date()
                    let currentTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

                    if(self.dateA! == date) {//compares if both times are the same.

                        let banner = Banner(title: alarm.alarmLabel!, subtitle: alarm.time!, image: UIImage(named: "alarmRing"), backgroundColor: UIColor(red:48.00/255.0, green:174.0/255.0, blue:51.5/255.0, alpha:1.000))//notification banner

                        banner.dismissesOnTap = true
                        banner.show(duration: 30.0)


                        if(banner.dismissesOnTap == true) {
                            stopSound()
                        }
                        else {
                            playSound()
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                    content.title = alarm.alarmLabel!
                    content.body = alarm.time!
                    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "Spaceship_Alarm.mp3")
                    let triggerTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: dateA!)
                    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerTime, repeats: true)
                    let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification"
                    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @ParasGorasiya I want to display in app notifications at a scheduled time in the tableView cellForRowAt function

Comment: You shouldn't do that into tableview delegate method, you may wish to define another function based on timer and that function will be called at your desired time and then you can perform your logic there and show in app notification.